# <input>: "required" não está setado, mesmo assim o preenchimento é exigido

Tags: html, html5, input

Eu tenho um input type url dentro de um form, e não setei o atributo "required" do mesmo, e mesmo assim o preenchimento do campo está sendo exigido. Eu tentei também: required="false" e required=false, e não adiantou...

```html
  <form method="dialog" id="form-cad-noticia" action="cadastrarNoticia">
        <input type="url" name="urlNoticia" placeholder="Insira aqui o link..." > <!--Aqui é o problema-->
        <input type="submit" value="CONFIRMAR">
    </form>
```

Pelo menos é o que está acontecendo na minha aplicação. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Ao que parece, não está sendo requerido o preenchimento, tanto que rodando o seu código, não aparece a mensagem. Talvez exista algum JS na sua aplicação que esteja fazendo esse tratamento?

Comment: O que acontece aí é que esse tipo **url** espera o sinal de **`:`** mesmo sem ter o atributo `required` no campo, é parecido com o tipo **email** por exemplo, se não inserir um **`@`** é mostrada a mensagem do navegador dizendo que está faltando o sinal.

Comment: Pode explicar  method="dialog" ? acho que vai funcionar sendo POST ou GET.

Comment: Não tem problema nenhum ai, se vc colocar um URL válido no campo funciona normal, assim como se vc não colocar nada no input tb funciona

Comment: @hugocsl Não funciona. E não tem javascript alterando isso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reiniciei tudo e funcionou, sem mexer nada